# How can I reference an aggregate column in another column in the same query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a query that looks more or less like this:

```
INSERT INTO #results
SELECT Name, 
        (SELECT 
            SUM(CAST(Amount AS BIGINT)) 
         FROM Items 
         WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
            and RecordId = 50), 
        (SELECT SUM(CAST(Std_Amount AS BIGINT)) 
         FROM Items 
         WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
            AND RecordId = 10)
FROM Member a
```

where `Amount` is a currency (stored as a varchar, without a decimal), `RemittingMember` is a link between the `Items` table and the `Member` table and `RecordId` indicates what type of item the row is. In this case, a 50 is a debit and a 10 is a credit.

I need to subtract the first column from the second column and have that value in a third column. I know I can do this as follows:

```
INSERT INTO #results
SELECT Name, 
            (SELECT 
                SUM(CAST(Amount AS BIGINT)) 
             FROM Items 
             WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
                and RecordId = 50), 
            (SELECT SUM(CAST(Std_Amount AS BIGINT)) 
             FROM Items 
             WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
                AND RecordId = 10),
             (SELECT 
                SUM(CAST(Amount AS BIGINT)) 
             FROM Items 
             WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
                and RecordId = 50) - (SELECT SUM(CAST(Std_Amount AS BIGINT)) 
             FROM Items 
             WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
                AND RecordId = 10)    
FROM Member a
```

But this is rather difficult to read and cumbersome to change if changes ever need to be made. I also know I can do this with local variables, but this is a report where `a.Number` will change which will involve iteration which I want to avoid.

I also need to check the sign of this third column to put a value in a fourth column.

Is there a clever way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE, something like this:

```
;WITH intermediate_results (name, debit, credit)
AS (
SELECT
    Name
    AS name, 

    (SELECT 
        SUM(CAST(Amount AS BIGINT)) 
     FROM Items 
     WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
        and RecordId = 50)
    AS debit, 

    (SELECT SUM(CAST(Std_Amount AS BIGINT)) 
     FROM Items 
     WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
        AND RecordId = 10)
    AS credit

FROM Member a
)

INSERT INTO #results
SELECT name, debit, credit, debit - credit, SIGN(debit - credit)
  FROM intermediate_results
```

Comment: *Update:* Added fifth column to resulting `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer apply` statement:

```
INSERT INTO #results
SELECT Name, 
        s1.Value, 
        s2.Value,
        s2.Value - s1.Value,
        case
            when s2.Value > s1.Value then 1
            when s2.Value < s1.Value then -1
            else 0
        end
FROM Member a
    outer apply (SELECT 
            SUM(CAST(Amount AS BIGINT)) Value
         FROM Items 
         WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
            and RecordId = 50) s1
    outer apply (SELECT 
            SUM(CAST(Std_Amount AS BIGINT)) Value
         FROM Items 
         WHERE RemittingMember = a.Number 
            and RecordId = 10) s2
```

Comment: You were first but a CTE is faster in my case :)

Comment: As I answered about CTE I like this answer too. BTW, maybe it was slower because of calculating sign column. `CASE` is too slow, try to use [`SIGN()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Also, add the fifth column to CTE answer and run your test again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify the query even more to remove an additional join onto the items table.  Something like this should work.  **Needs to be tested with your data**

```
SELECT
    name, 
    debit, 
    credit, 
    Amount = debit - credit, 
    [SIGN] = SIGN(debit - credit)
FROM Member a
inner join(
     SELECT 
        RemittingMember,
        debit=SUM(CASE WHEN RecordId = 50 THEN CAST(Amount AS BIGINT) ELSE 0 END),
        credit=SUM(CASE WHEN RecordId = 10 THEN CAST(Std_Amount AS BIGINT) ELSE 0 END)
     FROM Items 
     WHERE RecordId IN(10,50)
     GROUP BY
        RemittingMember
) as Amts
    on Amts.RemittingMember = a.Number
```